# WiFi not showing on Ubuntu 16.04 - Asus ROG GL502VMK

Tags: networking, drivers, asus

I have a problem with my Asus ROG GL502VMK and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. As in the subject my WiFi is not working properly, well it is not showing at all.

This are some information about my system:

```
GL502VMK 4.12.0-041200rc5-generic #201706112031 SMP Mon Jun 12 00:32:34 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the output of the wireless-info script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 21 Aug 2017 11:31 CEST +0200

Booted last: 21 Aug 2017 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.12.0-041200rc5-generic #201706112031 SMP Mon Jun 12 00:32:34 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:0010]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1837 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5666 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
iwlwifi               245760  0
cfg80211              602112  1 iwlwifi
wmi                    16384  2 asus_wmi,mxm_wmi
video                  40960  1 asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.5  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e257:3634:6662:8715/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2669 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1500 errors:4 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3881427 (3.8 MB)  TX bytes:99111 (99.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:154602 (154.6 KB)  TX bytes:154602 (154.6 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp4s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp4s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      2120     1  0 11:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/net/enp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp4s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Eth0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       12834e68-2439-49a3-9fb6-59685c3f02df
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0,1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   b8a089ac-1cc7-4eb2-bfb9-d8417a6003ab | RPi
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   12834e68-2439-49a3-9fb6-59685c3f02df | Eth0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.5/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1503394217
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::e257:3634:6662:8715/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Rome (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp4s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.12.0-041200rc5-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-30.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-30.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0--30.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0--30.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0--30.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0--30.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0--30.ucode
srcversion:     0805CCBBB378B21CD1488B6
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.12.0-041200rc5-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.12.0-041200rc5-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     41B6AD8CC3A348FE83EF412
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.12.0-041200rc5-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
d0i3_timeout: 1000
disable_11ac: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

coretemp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0.conf]
blacklist gspca_kinect

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   22.614088] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
[   22.716900] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link down
[   22.716970] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  404.446024] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link up
[  404.446040] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready
[  404.527157] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link down
[  406.536470] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link up

########## wireless info END ############
```

Under the additional drivers tab I have only two driver listed:

```
NVIDIA Corporation: NVIDIA binary-driver-version xxx
Unknown: Processor microcode firmware for intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)
```

Running dmesg gives me this error (partial output of dmesg):

```
    [    8.776888] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    8.776888] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[    8.777254] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.809110] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-30.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.813802] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-29.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.813809] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-28.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.814297] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.814356] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.814362] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.814368] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.814372] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.814390] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
[    8.814390] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    8.814406] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-8000C-22
[    8.814423] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-8000C-30
[    8.814439] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Under /lib/firmware/ I have:

```
iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode  iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode  iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
```

Maybe this last is the problem,  how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1704799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you're on `Linux 4.12.0-041200rc5-generic`. This is still in development and won't be part of Ubuntu until 17.10. You might have a great reason for running this but newer isn't always better and you're going to have to track security issues with this yourself.

If you are going to run on bleeding-edge Kernels, you might need to use bleeding edge firmware. You can see messages to this effect in your `dmesg` output:

```
[    8.814406] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-8000C-22
[    8.814423] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-8000C-30
```

Those firmware aren't in Ubuntu yet but you can grab a copy directly from the [`linux-firmware` tree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/). In this case, at the time of writing, you're probably after [`8000C-27.ucode`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode).

Comment: You are right, I am running this kernel because at the time I installed Ubuntu on this machine several things were not working (i.e. hotkeys and more).
I solved by upgrading the firmware as another post suggests by typing:
sudo wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.164_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb

Comment: That's fair enough if you need it, just be aware that Apt isn't updating things for you so you'll likely need to regularly install the latest version until you can move to 17.10 or 18.04. I'm not sure what kernel you were on before, but 4.10 is available in 16.04 as part of the zesty HWE pack.  Perhaps test a 17.04 live USB image.